# Returning istream& object to check if condition

Tags: c++

The book I am reading right now suggests to return `istream&` in `read()` function in order to be able to write something like this

```
if (read(cin, some_container)) {...}
```

However, when I try this code my function always returns false, no matter what. Where is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

istream& read(istream& in, vector<double>& s)
{
    if (in)
    {
        in.clear();

    double c;
    while (in >> c)
        s.push_back(c);
    }

    return in;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> r;
    if (read(cin, r))
        cout << "success" << endl;
    else
        cout << "false returned" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: How do you think your while loop ends?

Comment: I got you, while will end as soon as "in" as 0. But why does it end anyway? Even if I type a random word instead of double, I still fall out of the loop, but the question is why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::iostream` objects like `std::cin` [can be used in a bool context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to report **whether they are in an error state**.

Your `while` loop ends once `in` enters an error state, such as if you tried to read a random word as a `double`.

After your loop, the same `in` object is returned, used in an `if` context, and is evaluated as `false` again, since its state has not changed since it exited the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You return from the function when you break out of the following loop:

```
while (in >> c)
    s.push_back(c);
}
```

That loop breaks when `in` is in a state such that `if (in)` will be false.

You will need a different way testing whether `read` was successful or not. For example

1. If `r` has one or more values, consider `read` to be successful.
2. If `r` has 10 or more values, consider `read` to be successful.